# How to catch all Exceptions in a WPF program so that TextWriterTraceListener writes it to the log before crashing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a pretty normal WPF program (in VB.net but same should be no different to C#) and have implemented the TextWriterTraceListener which writes everything to a log file.  The issue I have is that if there is an exception that is uncaught then my app crashes and the log file seems to be "behind" so it does not show the very last entry before crashing.

1. Can I somehow make the TextWriterTraceListener write to the log file faster?
2. I have implemented the Application_DispatcherUnhandledException but this does not seem to catch my unhandled errors.

I am aware that on a proper close down I have to call flush and close on the TextWriterTraceListener object, the issue is that if my app crashes I don't get the opportunity to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomain_UnhandledException;
```

As well as your `Application_DispatcherUnhandledException`?

Comment: Thank you. This works fine and the exception is caught when running it from Visual Studio. But on a compiled .exe this event does not catch the exception and I have the same problem with the log file being only half complete.

Comment: Is it a particular exception that isn't caught or any exception? Are you using multiple threads? You say it works ok in Visual Studio - are you then testing it on the exact same compiled .exe that VS is running?

Comment: I dont know what I did but in my testing I think I have fixed it. Just so my experience matches your expertise - UnhandledException - seems to catch exceptions on non UI threads and the DispatcherUnhandledException seems to catch exceptions on the WPF UI thread? Is that how it should be?

Comment: Glad it works now. The code we have was developed several years ago and I know it caused us some pain to get right. Your thinking around the different handlers for UI and non-UI threads seems sound.